# Guardar valor de uma variável dentro de um controller para usar em método executado em outra DLL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, mvc

Preciso guardar uma informação no Login do Usuário e utilizar essa informação em outra DLL.

EX:

```
Projeto.Web
Projeto.Domain.dll
```

Ao logar o usuário no Projeto.Web controller UsuarioController, preciso guardar qual é o projeto que o usuário está logando, para isso criei uma classe estática na Projeto.Domain.dll e coloco o valor assim que o usuário se loga, mas quando vou usar esse valor em um método que está na dll Projeto.Domain ele encontra-se zerado, ou seja, ele perde o valor.

Qual a melhor forma de trabalhar com essa passagem de dados, pois tentei com Session e também não tive sucesso, creio que é devido a utilizar esse valor em DLL Class Library.......

Comment: Tentou ler o objeto session na dll assim: `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session` ?

Comment: O fato de acessar a `Session` em uma `Class Library` não é um problema. Porém armazenar informações do Usuário em um campo estatico, só não lhe dará problemas se o seu sistema tiver apenas um usuário.